# how to get cronjob running every minute

Tags: linux, fedora, cron

I am following advice on crontab usage online, and I ran `sudo crontab -e`, and my cron file is:

```
MAILTO=cchilder@mail.usf.edu

* * * * * /home/cchilders/scripts/python/scripts-in-progress/update_projects.py
```

It doesn't mail me anything, but worse, I am checking my git log for a project I made changes to, and update_projects is not running at all. When I run it by hand it works as expected. From everything I read, I really thought cronjobs were simple, and just needed a time (5 symbols) and path to a script.

I have tried testing the script calling to ensure both the python path and script path are correct. For this, I made crontest.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

/usr/bin/python /home/cchilders/scripts/python/scripts-in-progress/update_projects.py
```

Crontest.sh works when called from terminal. I have no uploaded it in user crontab, sudo crontab, and still it isn't running.

User crontab:

```
* * * * * /home/cchilders/scripts/bash/crontest.sh

* * * * * /home/cchilders/scripts/python/scripts-in-progress/update_projects.py
```

Sudo crontab:

```
MAILTO=cchilder@mail.usf.edu

* * * * * /home/cchilders/scripts/bash/crontest.sh

* * * * * /home/cchilders/scripts/python/scripts-in-progress/update_projects.py
```

What is wrong about this, if the pathway is correct? Thank you

update_projects.py looks as follows, and is working from terminal:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os, sys, time, subprocess
from os.path import expanduser

HOME = expanduser('~')

print 'running?


def call_sp(command, **arg_list):
    #run that
    p = subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True, **arg_list)
    p.communicate()


def get_project_path():
    i = 0
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(HOME):
        if i >= 2:
            return os.path.join(HOME, "projects")
        i += 1
        for this_dir in dirs:
            if this_dir == "django_practice":
                return os.path.join(HOME, "django_practice")

def update_projects(home_path):
    i = 0
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(home_path):
        for this_dir in dirs:
            if this_dir.startswith("."):
                continue
            full_path = os.path.join(root, this_dir)
            print full_path
            time.sleep(2)

            is_git_project = False
            j = 0
            for subroot, subdirs, subfiles in os.walk(full_path):
                if j >= 1:
                    break
                j += 1
                if not ".git" in subdirs:
                    break
                else:
                    is_git_project = True

            if not is_git_project:
                continue

            d = {'cwd': full_path}
            print 'git pull from {}'.format(full_path)
            call_sp('git pull', **d)
            time.sleep(2)
            call_sp('git add -A', **d)
            call_sp('git commit -m "automatic update"', **d)
            call_sp('git push', **d)
        dirs[:] = []

ppath = get_project_path()
update_projects(ppath)
```

Comment: 1) does your script have the executable bit set? 2) does your Python script have the Python shebang line at the start? `#!/usr/bin/env python`

Comment: ya, it's got it...idk what you mean by #1

Comment: the permissions are high, `-rwxrwxr-x.  ... 17:32 update_projects.py`

Comment: What happens if you put the script into your user's crontab instead of root's? (`crontab -e` instead of `sudo crontab -e`)

Comment: I've had problems because the `crontab` execution environment isn't the same as a normal terminal, and doesn't always have the same PATH variable. Try launching a shell script that explicitly runs `python` with its full path (returned by `which python`), followed by the full path to your script. I also notice that you are referencing `~` in the script: this will be the home directory of `root` if you launch it using `sudo`, so unless this is really where your files reside you should do as @ncdownpat suggests and run it from your user's `crontab`.

Comment: nothing happens when I put it in regular crontab, that was what I tried first. A solution suggested to do sudo, even though there's nothing fancy in my bitbucket script

Answer (score 1):

Put the /usr/bin/python in the crontab entry.

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/python /home/cchilders/scripts/python/scripts-in-progress/update_projects.py
```

Comment: surprisingly, even that didn't work. I tried it in user and sudo crontab